# How I export the models trained in google cloud to my pc?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, conv-neural-network

I trained my convolutional neural network implemented in tensorflow in google cloud, but now how do I export the model in "storage in google cloud" to my PC?

I want to download the model that was trained, to use it to make predictions

[I have it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDlYP.png)

Comment: Do you want to transfer files from Google compute Ubuntu machine to your PC?

Comment: I want to download the model that was trained, to use it to make predictions

Comment: I think you have saved it and want to transfer it ? I use the gcloud scp command  to transfer. Is this what you want ?

Comment: (I put an image in my question) yes I saved it in a bucket in google cloud

Comment: I don't understand the command gcloud compute scp --recurse [INSTANCE_NAME]:[REMOTE_DIR] [LOCAL_DIR]

The instance is the name of my file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your files are already in a bucket you can download them from the web interface by either clicking one by one and saving on your hard drive or you can use 
     `gsutil cp *.* gs://adeepdetectortraining-mlengine/prueba_27_BASIC_GPU`
[check here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp)

Comment: BUT I SEE THAT NO COMMAND ALLOWS ME TO DOWNLOAD THE WHOLE FOLDER

Answer (score 0):

To download recursively all the files and folders inside a bucket, I suggest you to use the gsutil command:

```
gsutil cp -r gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/<FOLDER>
```

The above command will download recursively the files and folders inside "FOLDER" on the current path for the local machine, this is possible due to the "-r" option is used.

You would be able to add a destination folder following the gsutil command [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp):

```
gsutil cp [OPTIONS] src_url dst_url
```

Where:

- src_url is the path for your bucket.
- dst_url is the path for your local machine.

Consider that above commands should be executed on your local machine with Cloud SDK [installed](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install) and [configured](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/initializing#run_gcloud_init), this will allow you to copy your files into your local machine.